# query on multiple databases best solution

Tags: mysql

i have 8 databases with same tables

```
db0
  tbluser |  id  |    name

db1
  tbluser |  id  |    name

db2
  tbluser

db3
   tbluser |  id  |    name

db4
   tbluser |  id  |    name

db5       
   tbluser |  id  |    name

db6       
   tbluser |  id  |    name

db7
   tbluser |  id  |    name
```

i have `another table dbcommon` where user messages saved

```
dbcommon
   message  |  id  |  sender_id  |  recipient_id
```

My problem is that I need to query all messages with user name in it based on sender id and recipient id

What is the best way to do this on mysql?

My approach now is to combine all db1 to db7 user data using union then inner join to message in dbcommon but i'm not sure if that would be ok, what if i have million of data
on user table select and union would be a trouble.

To better understand my question.
I made this but I will not use it.

```
select *, sender.nickname as sender_name, recipient.nickname as recipient_name
from dbcommon.message m
inner join
(
select * from db0.tbluser
union
select * from db1.tbluser
union
select * from db2.tbluser
union
select * from db3.tbluser
union
select * from db4.tbluser
union
select * from db5.tbluser
union
select * from db6.tbluser
union
select * from db7.tbluser
) as sender on m.sender_id = sender.id
inner join
(
select * from db0.tbluser
union
select * from db1.tbluser
union
select * from db2.tbluser
union
select * from db3.tbluser
union
select * from db4.tbluser
union
select * from db5.tbluser
union
select * from db6.tbluser
union
select * from db7.tbluser
) as recipient on m.recipient_id = recipient.id
```

Comment: why on earth do you have 8 distinct databases? i MAY understand if you had 8 similar tables (and even so, not that much), but 8 databases are crazy

Comment: If in any way possible, move the data to the same database instance. I know it isn't the scope of your question, but this architecture looks very wrong.

Comment: hmm i have japanese client and they provide me those databases, i cannot change the architecture, those tables are for game, the reason why they did that is for traffic handling, php code will choose which database a user will use once they enter the game

Comment: What is the relation between dbcommon and other db tables. Join the indexed field and see the cost of your query to check the performence.

Comment: Could you show the join with one table so we can see what you're trying to do?

Comment: Your notation is confusing. Is `tbluser` the name of the tables or a column in the table? Is `dbcommon` the name of a table or database?

Comment: @Barmar, moderator changed that, tbluser and message are tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst I *really* think that you should [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema such that all these tables are combined into a single one (perhaps with a suitable, indexed as desired, column that indicates the original database); I think that with the status quo, you have only two options:

1. Join a `UNION` to the `message` table, as you are currently doing (but, as you observe, this may not scale very well): you could define a [`VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/views.html) to save on having to explicitly state the `UNION` each time, but this won't have any performance benefit.
2. If `tbluser` tables all use the `MyISAM` storage engine, you can define a table of their union with [The `MERGE` Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/merge-storage-engine.html):

   ```
   CREATE TABLE dbcommon.tblusers LIKE db0.tbluser;

   ALTER  TABLE dbcommon.tblusers
     ENGINE = MERGE
     UNION  = (
                db0.tbluser, db1.tbluser, db2.tbluser, db3.tbluser,
                db4.tbluser, db5.tbluser, db6.tbluser, db7.tbluser
              )
   ;
   ```

   Joining this to your `message` table should yield significant performance benefit over the previous option.

Comment: i really want to normalize this databases but I'am not allowed to do it since the game is already running. What I'm doing is just adding new features.

Comment: @valrecx: There are ways to transition live systems to new schema.  Why not ask a question about that?

Comment: :( client don't want to do any changes to their existing databases

Comment: @valrecx: Then, if neither of the above solutions are suitable, client will have to suffer the consequences of their ridiculous decisions.

Comment: yup i know that, client don't listen to what developer says ahahaha

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this: (but this is not a good practice to have multiple database for same.

```
select d1.* from db1.dbcommon d1 inner join db2.tbluser d2 on d1.sender_id = d2.id 
UNION
select d1.* from db1.dbcommon d1 inner join db2.tbluser d2 on d1.sender_id = d2.id
```

Comment: check if it solves your problem. you have to use the inner joins to get the proper result against users.

Comment: I posted an answer like this, but deleted it after he pointed out that the sender can be in one DB and the receiver in another. You're missing the join on `receiver_id`.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
 SELECT NOME_USER, NOME_MAQ 
 FROM anapula.utilizador as a
    INNER JOIN cyber.maquinas as b ON a.ID_USER = b.COD_USER;
```